# Create a own user define network in docker and write own load balancing algorithm

Tags: docker, networking

I am working on a research project where I have to create an architecture of a number of worker nodes and a master node.

I want to write load balancing algorithm and test on these nodes(they have applications running on them). I have started studying Docker and I want to use it to create the architecture.

I am unable to decide which network type to use, as docker networking structure is quiet vast. They have created lot of abstractions over the Linux network drivers.

Should I use a bridge or an overlay network?

I want all worker node to send their CPU and memory usage to the master node. Basically worker can talk to the master. Then I will write load balancing algorithms over the master container node.

Need guidance from a networking expert in Docker. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single-host setup then you generally should use "bridge".  (You should declare *some* network in this case to take advantage of the inter-container DNS.)

If you have a multi-host setup then there are many setups you can use; valid options include Docker Swarm, Hashicorp's Nomad, Kubernetes, a hand-built setup around a service-discovery intermediary like Consul, or a hand-built setup where each directly service knows about the other nodes' host names and ignores the Docker layer.

If you are using Docker Swarm then you need to use "overlay".  But each of the options I described above uses a different networking setup (Kubernetes uses a piece called CNI, and there are a dozen different implementation choices within this, for instance) and this question isn't directly meaningful for many of them.

As you're describing the project it sounds like you want to explicitly place applications on specific nodes, and manage the routing between them manually.  For this I'd probably use "bridge" networking only: launch Docker containers using `-p` (or Docker Compose `ports:`) options to publish ports on the host IP addresses, and communicate between containers using only those host IP addresses.  That will give you a useful level of manual control for a research project.

Comment: Thanks, I also found bridge network would be best. Carrying on further work. Will get back if any issue.

Comment: So I created a bridge network and attached 4 containers to it. I can ping all the containers in the bridge network. I have some more questions. 1) Can I make one of the containers among all containers in the Bridge network as master node? Can I give rights to master by which it can start and stop applications on other non master nodes? How will other non master containers send their CPU usage to the master node? My aim would is to write algorithm(with will be the main research) on master node which will schedule applications on worker/non master nodes and do other load balancing stuff?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "master", "application", and "node", but none of this is impossible.  Consul, Elasticsearch, ZooKeeper, and etcd all have leader-election mechanisms that lets one instance of a connected cluster be "master" (especially look up the Raft paper); one Docker container starting others on the same host requires access to the host's Docker socket but otherwise is well-established; at a high level it sounds almost like you're trying to build a container cluster manager like Nomad or Kubernetes.

Comment: I am not going on high level. Node is a container in bridge network. Master again will be a container among all the containers in on the bridge network. I don't want to make master election but just making any node as one which has more rights as it can start and stop a applications or services running on other containers. That leader will be a static leader not a changing one. Is there a way to do by some simple command on docker?

Comment: I studied docker swarm and found it is  creating customer docker swarm on a low level. How to start with it? is there a good documentation to create such a custom network?